# Date format using multiple languages

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, date

I have 2 simple xml files to provide news stories to a website MVC4. I have one in English and one in Georgian

Examples

```
<ITEM id="7" Title="English"
    Content="English Content"
    dt ="02/11/2013">
</ITEM>

<ITEM id="7" Title="ქართული"
    Content="ქართული შინაარსი"
    dt ="02/11/2013">
</ITEM>
```

I create a model to put the data into and NB I set a date format here:

```
public class NewsModel
{
    public Int32 id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Content { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DT { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel which provides a list and determines which language I need:

```
public NewsListModel()
    {
        try
        {
            String cultureStr = HttpContext.Current.Session["Culture"].ToString();

            if (cultureStr == "en-GB" || cultureStr == "en-US")
            {
                xmlurl = "http://localhost:1703/News/NewsENG.xml";
            }
            else
            {
                xmlurl = "http://localhost:1703/News/NewsGEO.xml";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            xmlurl = "http://localhost:1703/News/NewsGEO.xml";
        }

        _newslist = new ObservableCollection<NewsModel>();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlurl);

        XmlNode ItemListNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("ITEMS");
        XmlNodeList ItemNodes = ItemListNode.SelectNodes("ITEM");

        foreach (XmlNode i in ItemNodes)
        {
            NewsModel n = new NewsModel();
            n.id = Convert.ToInt32(i.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value);
            n.Title = i.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Title").Value.ToString();
            n.Content = i.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Content").Value.ToString();
            n.DT = Convert.ToDateTime(i.Attributes.GetNamedItem("dt").Value);
            _newslist.Add(n);
        }
    }
```

I then display in the page:

```
@itm.DT.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

My problem is that my date format is different dependent on the language used i.e.

[image]
[image]

Removing the .ToShortDateString() has the same separator problem and displays the time.

I have looked through this so many times now. I seem to be doing the same with each file. Has anyone had a similar experience and/or a resolution so that both date formats display the same with "/" as separator.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the desired culture or format to your model (to the root of you model, not to each element of the list).

Then, simply use the culture or format in your view, like this:

```
  @itm.DT.Date.ToShortDateString(/* here the format/culture*/ Model.Culture)
```

In this way you don't depend on any magic...

If you want a different format for echa item in the list, add the format culture to each element.

When you cannot get it automatically... be explicit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Based on your comment. Is it the Georgian culture setting that is putting . instead of / as a separator?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (assuming that your model has an `Items` property of type `IEnumerable<NewsModel>`):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Items[index].DT) // index from a for loop
```

Your `DisplayFormatAttribute` on `DT` is ignored when you directly write `@itm.DT`